# Postman script: Is it possible to set a variable in a different environment?

Tags: postman

I have several test scripts in postman where a set environment variables, but now i need to set a variable in a different environment from the one that is selected.
Is it possible?

Comment: Use global variables

Comment: Thanks Div. 
I know that i can use it, but its impossible to do what i asked?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do that via a `pm.*.set()` function but you could use the Postman API in a `pm.sendRequest()` to create or edit an environment file. https://docs.api.getpostman.com/?version=latest